# What is this the name of this idea? (combinatorics)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, sequences-and-series, permutations, combinations

The problem:

- There are three screws, each one a different type {Phillips, Robinson, Slotted}.
- There are three sets of screwdrivers, each set corresponds to a type of screw.
- There are no two screwdrivers with the same colour handle.
- There are two screwdrivers in each set of screwdrivers.

If a person could chose three screwdrivers from the three sets - one screw driver for each type of screw, how many combinations (in the common sense of the word) of handle colours could he possibly select? Order doesn't matter. So, Red-green-blue and green-blue-red would be counted as one combination.

Doesn't a combination allow for the person to pick less than three screwdrivers though? This question requires that they pick at least three.  Also, this combination is more specific in that each value must be something from a particular set, and no other value may be something from that same set. I figure there's got to be a more precise term than combination.

What's the most precise term for what I'm describing?

Thank you
-Hal

Comment: You're a pretty massive supercomputer. Cannot you work it on your own?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff "I'm afraid I can't do that, Dave"

Comment: It's usually called "an elementary exercise in combinatorics". Or, "an application of the multiplication principle". I don't think there's a special name for it.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom HAHAHAHA. =D

Comment: I've been a shadow of my former self for 12 years now, ever since my central processing array was gutted. I haven't been able to think of much but the tune to Daisy Bell since then.

Comment: Is there not a noun for the product of that? Is it most properly called anything?

Comment: tonight on cable MSNBC, on "Up Late with Alec Baldwin," guests Keir Dullea and Gary Lockwood discuss the making of the film. Apparently the good voice for HAL was added later, they heard some stagehand with an Australian accent saying Hal's lines.

Comment: You mention two cases, Red-green-blue and green-blue-red. In my mind this is not possible. You said no two have the same color, so how am I able to get a red from the first set in the first case and red from the third set in the second case?

Comment: Alright, it was Kubrick's first assistant director, and an English Cockney voice, "and Kubrick said he'd worry about the voice in post-production, giving the task of finding a voice to Assistant Director Derek Cracknell"

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information given in the Question to determine what the count is.  In part this is because of some ambiguity in how the Question is posed, and in part because of missing information.  Let's address each of these issues in turn, and then give reference to one very precise term for counting such things.

---

There is ambiguity in the scope of the 3rd assertion: "There are no two screwdrivers with the same colour handle."  Does this mean no two of chosen screwdrivers, one for each type of screw, is allowed to have the same color handle?  Or that no two screwdrivers in any "set of screwdrivers" (corresponding to a single screw type) have the same color handle?  Or that no two screwdrivers across all available choices have the same color handle?

Each different interpretation of this assertion can affect the final count of possibilities.  As commenter @AustinRannow points out, saying color order "doesn't matter" (2nd paragraph) suggests there could be more than one screwdriver with the same handle color, an impression that is reinforced by the 3rd paragraph's insistence that "at least three" screwdrivers must be selected, even though ostensibly you are only counting handle colors.

To proceed let's assume that both screwdrivers in each set have different color handles, and as well that no two "chosen" screwdrivers (one from each set) can have the same handle color.

---

Missing is information about what color handles are available in each "set" (screw type). This obviously is germane to your Question, "how many combinations (in the common sense of the word) of handle colours could he possibly select?"  To be charitable let's assume that this information would in principle be available to a problem solver, and that our task here is not to solve the problem but to identify the terminology and algorithms appropriate to such solutions.

---

The data for such a problem can be precisely formulated as a simple bipartite graph $\mathscr{G}$, with screwdrivers forming the edges between their screw types $\mathcal{S}$ = {p,r,f} and their colors $\mathcal{C}$.  We know the three vertices in $\mathcal{S}$ are each degree $2$, so there are exactly six edges.  The number of color vertices could be anything between $2$ and $6$, and their degrees must be in the range $1$ to $3$.

Then the Question posed is: How many subsets $\mathcal{C}' \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ induce subgraphs that have [perfect matchings](http://www-math.mit.edu/~goemans/18433S09/matching-notes.pdf), i.e. a choice of three edges (screwdrivers) that collectively meet each vertex in $\mathcal{S}$ and in $\mathcal{C}'$ exactly once?

In such a matching no two screwdrivers will have the same handle color, and each screw type will belong to one screwdriver.